# How to retrieve some specific rows and columns from an excel sheet?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, data-formatters

- I am reading an xlsx file using java (Apache POI).
- I have created a Document class (having all excel column heading as variables)
- i have to read each row in the excel and map to the Document class by creating a collection of Document class.
- The problem I am facing is that I have to start reading from row 2 and from column 7 to column 35 and map the corresponding values to the document class.
- Unable to to figure out exactly how the code should be ?
- I have written the following lines of code.

```
 List sheetData = new ArrayList();
        InputStream excelFile = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("D:\\Excel file\\data.xlsx"));
        Workbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile); // Creates Workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) workBook.getSheet("Daily");
        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
        for (int i = 7; i <= 35; i++) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
            Cell cell = row.getCell(i);
            String val = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
            sheetData.add(val);
        }
```

Comment: What isn't working with your code posted?

Comment: It's only fetching 1 row from the excel. There are 400 rows & 30 columns in the excel sheet. I have to fetch data from row no. 2 and from column no. 7 onwards till the end. How can I do that codewise? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Got my question right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, I believe you want to process every row which exists from row 2 onwards to the end of the file, and for each of those rows consider the cells in columns 7 through 35. I believe you also might need to process those values, but you haven't said how, so for this example I'll just stuff them in a list of strings and hope for the best...

This is based on the [Apache POI documentation for iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)

```
File excelFile = new File("D:\\Excel file\\data.xlsx");
Workbook workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(excelFile);
Sheet sheet = workBook.getSheet("Daily");
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

// Start from the 2nd row, processing all to the end
// Note - Rows and Columns in Apache POI are 0-based not 1-based
for (int rn=1; rn<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); rn++) {
   Row row = sheet.getRow(rn);
   if (row == null) {
      // Whole row is empty. Handle as required here
      continue;
   }
   List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
   for (int cn=6; cn<35; cn++) {
      Cell cell = row.getCell(cn);
      String val = null;
      if (cell != null) { val = formatter.formatCellValue(cell); }
      if (val == null || val.isEmpty()) {
         // Cell is empty. Handle as required here
      }
      // Save the value to list. Save to an object instead if required
      values.append(val);
   }
}
workBook.close();
```

Depending on your business requirements, put in logic for handling blank rows and cells. Then, do whatever you need to do with the values you find, again as per your business requirements!

Comment: Thanks for the code @Gagravarr After fetching the values, I have to map the cell values of each row in the excel to the java class I have created and push the data to mongo db.. The problem I am facing here is when I am setting the obtained string value to the variables of the class, it's reading only one value and setting the same for all the fields.

Comment: You probably want to ask a brand new question on turning the strings into your mongodb wrapper then

Comment: Yes..How can I do it ?

Comment: In the top right of the page, click "Ask Question" just as you did before, and describe your new problem with mapping the strings to the fields

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate with an Iterator in the document, but there is also an function "getRow() and getCell()"

```
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);

  // defines the standard pointer in document in the first Sheet
  XSSFSheet data = this.workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  // you could iterate the document with an iterator
  Iterator<Cell> iterator = this.data.iterator();

  // x/y pointer at the document
  Row row = data.getRow(y);
  Cell pointingCell = row.getCell(x);

  String pointingString = pointingCell.getStringCellValue();
```

Comment: I cannot use iterators. I can only use DataFormatter. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why arent you able to use Iterators?

Comment: Using iterator implies waste of lines of code here.